# "\\" escape sequence not working in python shell

Tags: python, string, shell, escaping, backslash

when i type 'hello\'s' into the python shell, it outputs 'hello's' but when I type "\\" the output is '\\' instead of '\'. Additionally when I use triple quotes:

```
>>>'''hello
...world''' 
"hello\nworld"
```

Why does the output have double quotes? and why did they convert the separate lines to '\n' the newline character. This is weird, because the print function for example, usually converts the newline character to an actual newline, but the shell seems to do the reverse.
Could someone explain all this?

Comment: It's showing what you would have to type to create the string. Since backslash is an escape character, you have to double it to make it literal.

Comment: Use `print()` to see the output in human format, rather than the input representation.

Comment: @Barmar I did put a double backslash, but it didn't become a literal. And it the shell doesn't return the pure input representation, because the escape sequence for " \' " works in the python shell.

Comment: Single quote doesn't need to be escaped inside a double-quoted string, so it doesn't show it with the backslash.

Comment: It only escapes characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: Putting backslash before other characters is redundant and ignored.

Comment: The shell shows the representation of the string. That's different from what you get when you print the value. Compare `print("hello\nworld")` and `print(repr("hello\nworld"))`.